# Active attribute is not setting with the div's class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to Create a inbox notification. It is successfully opening and closing. But it is only opening and closing when the open button is inside the div. But I am trying to open the notification when the `Open button` is `outside` the `panel div`, so I created an `onClick` event to `remove` and `open` **active** class. But when I click on *open Button* then it is not opening or closing:

```js
// My onClick event

function openInbox() {
    gettingOpen = document.getElementsByTagName("myDiv");
    gettingOpen[0].setAttribute("myNotification", "active");
}


// Previous script to open and close which is working fine

$(".myNotification .icon_wrap").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("active");
});

$(".show_all .link").click(function(){
    $(".myNotification").removeClass("active");
    $(".popup").show();
});

$(".close, .shadow").click(function(){
    $(".popup").hide();
});

$(".myB").click(function(){
    $(".myNotification").removeClass("active");
});
```

```css
.myNavbar .navbar_left .logo a{
   font-family: 'Trade Winds';
   font-size: 20px;
}

.myNavbar .navbar_right{
   display: flex;
}

.myNavbar .navbar_right img{
  width: 35px;
}

.myNavbar .navbar_right .icon_wrap{
  cursor: pointer;
}

.myNavbar .navbar_right .myNotification{
  margin-left: 505px;
}

.myNavbar .navbar_right .myNotification .icon_wrap{
  font-size: 28px;
}

.myNavbar .navbar_right .myProfile,
.myNavbar .navbar_right .myNotification{
  position: relative;
}

.myNavbar .profile_dd,
.notification_dd{
  position: absolute;
  top: 18px;
  right: -10px;
  user-select: none;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #c7d8e2;
  width: 350px;
  padding: 3em;
  height: auto;
  display: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125),
              -10px -10px 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
}

.myNavbar .myProfile .profile_dd ul li .btn{
    height: 32px;
    padding: 7px 10px;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    background: #3b80f9;
    width: 125px;
    margin: 5px auto 15px;
}

.myNavbar .myProfile .profile_dd ul li .btn:hover{
  background: #6593e4;
}

.myNavbar .myProfile.active .profile_dd,
.myNavbar .myNotification.active .notification_dd{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/hung1001/font-awesome-pro@4cac1a6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div onClick="openInbox();">Open inbox Here(not working)</div>

<div class="myNavbar">
    <div class="navbar_right">
        <myDiv class="myNotification" id="Notif">
        <a class="icon_wrap" action=""><i class="far fa-bell"></i></a>

            <div class="notification_dd">
                This is Notification Div
            </div>
        </myDiv>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you noticed, I am running a function named `openInbox` to set the `active` attribute with `myNotifiction`. But why is the div is not opening ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a CSS class, you don't use `setAttribute`, but instead use [element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList):

```
gettingOpen[0].classList.toggle("active");
```

```js
// My onClick event

function openInbox() {
    gettingOpen = document.getElementsByTagName("myDiv");
    gettingOpen[0].classList.toggle("active");

}


// Previous script to open and close which is working fine

$(".myNotification .icon_wrap").click(function(){
  $(this).parent().toggleClass("active");
});

$(".show_all .link").click(function(){
  $(".myNotification").removeClass("active");
  $(".popup").show();
});

$(".close, .shadow").click(function(){
  $(".popup").hide();
});

$(".myB").click(function(){
  $(".myNotification").removeClass("active");
});
```

```css
.myNavbar .navbar_left .logo a{
   font-family: 'Trade Winds';
   font-size: 20px;
}

.myNavbar .navbar_right{
   display: flex;
}

.myNavbar .navbar_right img{
  width: 35px;
}

.myNavbar .navbar_right .icon_wrap{
  cursor: pointer;
}

.myNavbar .navbar_right .myNotification{
  margin-left: 505px;
}

.myNavbar .navbar_right .myNotification .icon_wrap{
  font-size: 28px;
}

.myNavbar .navbar_right .myProfile,
.myNavbar .navbar_right .myNotification{
  position: relative;
}

.myNavbar .profile_dd,
.notification_dd{
  position: absolute;
  top: 18px;
  right: -10px;
  user-select: none;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #c7d8e2;
  width: 350px;
  padding: 3em;
  height: auto;
  display: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 35px rgba(0,0,0,0.125),
              -10px -10px 35px rgba(0,0,0,0.125);
}

.myNavbar .myProfile .profile_dd ul li .btn{
    height: 32px;
    padding: 7px 10px;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    background: #3b80f9;
    width: 125px;
    margin: 5px auto 15px;
}

.myNavbar .myProfile .profile_dd ul li .btn:hover{
  background: #6593e4;
}

.myNavbar .myProfile.active .profile_dd,
.myNavbar .myNotification.active .notification_dd{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/hung1001/font-awesome-pro@4cac1a6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div onClick="openInbox();">Open inbox Here(not working)</div>

<div class="myNavbar">
    <div class="navbar_right">
        <myDiv class="myNotification" id="Notif">
        <a class="icon_wrap" action=""><i class="far fa-bell"></i></a>

            <div class="notification_dd">
                This is Notification Div
            </div>
        </myDiv>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add classes using [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute), then you've to use the function like below.

```
function openInbox() {
    gettingOpen = document.getElementsByTagName("myDiv");
    gettingOpen[0].setAttribute("class","myNotification active");
}
```

Here is your code modified:

```js
// My onClick event

function openInbox() {
  gettingOpen = document.getElementsByTagName("myDiv");
  gettingOpen[0].setAttribute("class","myNotification active");
}


// Previous script to open and close which is working fine

$(".myNotification .icon_wrap").click(function(){
  $(this).parent().toggleClass("active");
});

$(".show_all .link").click(function(){
  $(".myNotification").removeClass("active");
  $(".popup").show();
});

$(".close, .shadow").click(function(){
  $(".popup").hide();
});

$(".myB").click(function(){
  $(".myNotification").removeClass("active");
});
```

```css
.myNavbar .navbar_left .logo a{
   font-family: 'Trade Winds';
   font-size: 20px;
}

.myNavbar .navbar_right{
   display: flex;
}

.myNavbar .navbar_right img{
  width: 35px;
}

.myNavbar .navbar_right .icon_wrap{
  cursor: pointer;
}

.myNavbar .navbar_right .myNotification{
  margin-left: 505px;
}

.myNavbar .navbar_right .myNotification .icon_wrap{
  font-size: 28px;
}

.myNavbar .navbar_right .myProfile,
.myNavbar .navbar_right .myNotification{
  position: relative;
}

.myNavbar .profile_dd,
.notification_dd{
  position: absolute;
  top: 18px;
  right: -10px;
  user-select: none;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #c7d8e2;
  width: 350px;
  padding: 3em;
  height: auto;
  display: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 35px rgba(0,0,0,0.125),
              -10px -10px 35px rgba(0,0,0,0.125);
}

.myNavbar .myProfile .profile_dd ul li .btn{
    height: 32px;
    padding: 7px 10px;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    background: #3b80f9;
    width: 125px;
    margin: 5px auto 15px;
}

.myNavbar .myProfile .profile_dd ul li .btn:hover{
  background: #6593e4;
}

.myNavbar .myProfile.active .profile_dd,
.myNavbar .myNotification.active .notification_dd{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/hung1001/font-awesome-pro@4cac1a6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


<div onClick="openInbox();">Open inbox Here(not working)</div>





<div class="myNavbar">
    <div class="navbar_right">
        <myDiv class="myNotification" id="Notif">
        <a class="icon_wrap" action=""><i class="far fa-bell"></i></a>

            <div class="notification_dd">
                This is Notification Div
            </div>
        </myDiv>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have did following change in your JavaScript code:

```
function openInbox() {
    gettingOpen = document.getElementsByTagName("myDiv");
    gettingOpen[0].setAttribute("myNotification","active");
}
```

Changed to

```
function opentInbox(){
  $(".myNotification").toggleClass("active");
};
```

**Updated Code Snippet**

```js
// My onClick event

function opentInbox(){
  $(".myNotification").toggleClass("active");
};



// Previous script to open and close which is working fine

$(".myNotification .icon_wrap").click(function(){
  $(this).parent().toggleClass("active");
});

$(".show_all .link").click(function(){
  $(".myNotification").removeClass("active");
  $(".popup").show();
});

$(".close, .shadow").click(function(){
  $(".popup").hide();
});

$(".myB").click(function(){
  $(".myNotification").removeClass("active");
});
```

```css
.myNavbar .navbar_left .logo a{
   font-family: 'Trade Winds';
   font-size: 20px;
}

.myNavbar .navbar_right{
   display: flex;
}

.myNavbar .navbar_right img{
  width: 35px;
}

.myNavbar .navbar_right .icon_wrap{
  cursor: pointer;
}

.myNavbar .navbar_right .myNotification{
  margin-left: 505px;
}

.myNavbar .navbar_right .myNotification .icon_wrap{
  font-size: 28px;
}

.myNavbar .navbar_right .myProfile,
.myNavbar .navbar_right .myNotification{
  position: relative;
}

.myNavbar .profile_dd,
.notification_dd{
  position: absolute;
  top: 18px;
  right: -10px;
  user-select: none;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #c7d8e2;
  width: 350px;
  padding: 3em;
  height: auto;
  display: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 35px rgba(0,0,0,0.125),
              -10px -10px 35px rgba(0,0,0,0.125);
}

.myNavbar .myProfile .profile_dd ul li .btn{
    height: 32px;
    padding: 7px 10px;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    background: #3b80f9;
    width: 125px;
    margin: 5px auto 15px;
}

.myNavbar .myProfile .profile_dd ul li .btn:hover{
  background: #6593e4;
}

.myNavbar .myProfile.active .profile_dd,
.myNavbar .myNotification.active .notification_dd{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/hung1001/font-awesome-pro@4cac1a6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


<div onClick="opentInbox();">Open inbox Here(not working)</div>

<div class="myNavbar">
    <div class="navbar_right">
        <div class="myNotification" id="Notif">
           <a class="icon_wrap" action=""><i class="far fa-bell"></i></a>

            <div class="notification_dd">
                This is Notification Div
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? What did you change exactly and ***why***? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69869971/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, use `Element.classList` rather than `setAttribute`.

`Element.classList` is read-only property that returns a live DOMTokenList collection of the class attributes of the element. You can modify its associated DOMTokenList using the `add()`, `remove()`, `replace()`, and `toggle()` methods.

You can update your `openInbox()` method accordingly.

```
function openInbox() {
    gettingOpen = document.getElementsByTagName("myDiv");
    gettingOpen[0].classList.toggle("active");
}
```